# Matching blank entries in django queryset for optional field with corresponding ones in a required field

Tags: python, django

I have a django queryset in my views  whose values I pack before passing to my template. There is a problem when the queryset returns `none` since associated values are not unpacked. the quersyet is called `comments`.

Here is my views.py

```
def forums(request ):


post_list = list(forum.objects.filter(child='0')&forum.objects.filter(deleted='0').order_by('postDate'))
user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
newpostform = PostForm(request.POST)
deletepostform = PostDeleteForm(request.POST)
DelPostFormSet = modelformset_factory(forum, exclude=('child','postSubject','postBody','postPoster','postDate','childParentId'))
readform = ReadForumForm(request.POST)
comments =list( forum.objects.filter(deleted='0').filter(child='1').order_by('childParentId').values('childParentId').annotate(y=Count('childParentId')))


if request.user.is_staff== True :
    staff = 1
else:
    staff = 0
staffis = 1




if newpostform.is_valid():
    topic = request.POST['postSubject']
    poster = request.POST['postPoster']
    newpostform.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/forums')

else:
    newpostform = PostForm(initial = {'postPoster':user.id})

if request.GET:
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if form.is_valid():
        query = form.cleaned_data['query']
        post_list = list((forum.objects.filter(child='0')&forum.objects.filter(deleted='0')&forum.objects.filter(Q(postSubject__icontains=query)|Q(postBody__icontains=query)|Q(postDate__icontains=query)))or(forum.objects.filter(deleted='0')&forum.objects.filter(Q(postSubject__icontains=query)|Q(postBody__icontains=query)|Q(postDate__icontains=query)).values('childParentId')))

if request.method == 'POST':
    delpostformset = DelPostFormSet(request.POST)
    if delpostformset.is_valid():
        delpostformset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/forums')

else:
    delpostformset = DelPostFormSet(queryset=forum.objects.filter(child='0', deleted='0'))



"""if readform.is_valid():
    user=get_object_or_404(UserProfile.objects.all())
    readform.save()
else:
    readform = ReadForumForm()"""

post= zip( post_list,comments, delpostformset.forms)
paginator = Paginator(post, 10) # Show 10 contacts per page

# Make sure page request is an int. If not, deliver first page.
try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
except ValueError:
    page = 1

# If page request (9999) is out of range, deliver last page of results.
try:
    post = paginator.page(page)
except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
    post = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response('forum.html', {'post':post, 'newpostform': newpostform,'delpost':delpostformset, 'username':user.username, 'comments':comments, 'user':user,  },context_instance = RequestContext( request ))
```

I realised that the issue was with the `comments` queryset `comments =list( forum.objects.filter(deleted='0').filter(child='1').order_by('childParentId').values('childParentId').annotate(y=Count('childParentId')))` which will only returns values for posts that have comments. so i now need a way to return 0 comments when a value in `post-list` `post_list = list(forum.objects.filter(child='0')&forum.objects.filter(deleted='0').order_by('postDate'))` does not have any comments (optional field).

Here is my models.py

```
class forum(models.Model):
    postID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    postSubject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postBody = models.TextField()
    postPoster = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    postDate =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    child = models.BooleanField()
    childParentId = models.ForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u' %d' % ( self.postID)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just do this:

```
comments = list(queryset or [])
```

if the queryset resolves to None, then the empty list will be used and `comments` will just be an empty list.

Comment: this still does not work for `post_list = list(forum.objects.filter(child='0')&forum.objects.filter(deleted='0').order_by('postDate'))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing it right. I don't believe that queryset can return None. Why not just chain the `filter` methods?

```
list(forum.objects.filter(child='0').filter(deleted='0').order_by('postDate'))
```

If you have more complex queries, you can use the [Query objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) of django, which allow you to use the `&` and `|` logical operators.

Comment: yeah, it does not return none. the problem is that am zipping the values from both queries , `post-list` and 'comments' and hence they need to be equal in number , but `comments` only returns values if a value in `post-list` has comments. so how do I compensate such that I always get a '0' in comments if 'post-list` has no comments.

Comment: `zip` does not require both lists to have the same length. Please explain **exactly** and **concisely** what your problem is and I am sure a solution will be found.

Comment: Olivier, my problem is using the `comments` query. I need it to get the number of 'childParentId` for each distinct `postID`. `childParentId` is used to indicate comments for a post with a certain `postId` hence the 2 will be similar for a post and its comments. So far, I am my code works for posts with comments , but takes all uncommented posts as 1 post( since the `childParentId` for all uncommmented posts is `None`